# Kernel killed due to RAM memory leak in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have a utility code that takes as input the class probabilities as predicted by two image classification models `M1` and `M2`. The utility code calculates a modified version of the AUC metric. The output of model `M1` is passed to the utility code and no error is thrown. However, the output of model `M2` when passed to the utility code throws an error as described next.

The jupyter notebook shows ‘`kernel has been killed`’. A little bit more digging into the error shows that the error comes due to RAM memory being full (GPU memory is 24GB is less than 80% occupied) and the kernel is getting killed. I have also localized the line of code where the error is actually happening. The kernel is killed i.e. RAM is overflows (it is worth noting that I am using a 128GB RAM machine with pytorch 2.1, ubuntu 20.04) when the model executes the following code

> score[~mask]+=bias

I have the following dimensions of the variables and data types

`print(score.data_type, score.shape, mask.data_type, mask.shape)`

`<class 'torch.Tensor'>, torch.Size([7280]), <class 'torch.Tensor'>,torch.Size([7280, 278362]),`

Also the output from `M1` and `M2` are not same. The outputs are dictionaries with class labels as keys and values as probabilities. The output of M1 is as follows,

> print(pred_M1[‘class_0’])

`tensor(0.5000),`

> print(pred_M2[‘class_0’])

`tensor(0.5000))`

However the following output is also observed,

> print(pred_M1[‘class_0’].item())

`0.5000015497207642`

What can be the cause of memory leak in the RAM? Any help in this regard will be highly helpful.